# automatically updating the sysdate functionality in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I want to run everyday that needs to use the sysdate function in oracle sql. I want to be able to see how my query/data is doing on  a daily basis without having to go in and change the number that I am subtracting from the sysdate. As you can see below I don't want to change "60" to "61" or "62" every time another day passes.

Example:

```
SELECT COLUMN_1
FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE SOME_DATE < SYSDATE - 60 
;
```

I know that there are probably many different ways to get around this but I can't seem to find one that works for me.

Comment: And TO_DATE() doesn't work because ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As easy as:

```
SELECT COLUMN_1
FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE SOME_DATE > DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD' -- starting date like '2018-01-01'
```